# Not able to convert all elements of RelativeLaout to Bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a relative layout as follows

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/screen_shot_relative_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white">

            <include layout="@layout/news_content_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The `news_content_layout.xml` is as follow:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

//some elements of code

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/share_footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_below="@id/news_content">

            //Some more elements

     </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**What I am trying to do?**

I am trying to convert `screen_shot_relative_layout` (Relative Layout) to Bitmap.

Before converting layout to bitmap I am changing the `GONE` visibility of `share_footer` to  `VISIBLE`.

**Problem:**
The bitmap does not have the `share_footer`. But I can see that in the UI(on Device screen)

**My java code:**

```
    RelativeLayout mShareScreenShotRelativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.screen_shot_relative_layout);
    RelativeLayout mShareFooterRelativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.share_footer);
```

After clicking Share buttom:

```
//Making footer_layout visible
mShareFooterRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Bitmap bitmap = null;
Uri bitmapUri = null;
bitmap = Utils.viewToBitmap(mShareScreenShotRelativeLayout); //This convets the Layout to image
String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(mContext.getContentResolver(), bitmap, String.valueOf(articleId), null);

//Sharing the content
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                    sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some Text");
sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
mContext.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"))

//Making  footer_layout visibility GONE
mShareFooterRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The `bitmap` does not have `share_footer`. Please tell 
                                        bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);

I am not sure why this is happening. The footer is part of the parent and only visibility is Gone. Please help me in understanding what is wrong?

**EDIT :** I am 100% sure there is some delay to refresh the view. Till the View is getting refreshed by Bitmap gets generated.

**Now Question is How to handle this?**

Comment: Is there anything that making view Visible takes time. Or is there anything that I need to do like wait to refresh view??? Kindly help.

Comment: @CommonsWare can you help?

Answer (score 0):

use this way

```
public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

and call this way

```
viewToBitmap(mShareFooterRelativeLayout);
```

Comment: My `Utils.viewToBitmap(mShareScreenShotRelativeLayout)` method has same code.